# Почему функция fileno в Си имеет такое название?

Tags: c

Конкретно меня интересует, что означает "no".

Comment: ````номер, Nº````

Comment: @MBo спросил гугл _"Подпрограмма _fileno возвращает дескриптор файла, в данный момент связанный с stream"_, _"Функция fileno() определяет дескриптор файла открытого потока данных по указателю на управляющую таблицу потока данных."_. При чем тут номер?

Comment: @Kromster Дескриптор - число, некий номер файла в системе. Аналогично - функция `errno`

Comment: Хех, по fileno + errno нагуrлилось: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391062/fileno-errno-what-does-the-no-mean-non-native-english Можно связать вопросы.

Comment: Т.е. получается с `errno` однозначно, а `fileno` немного притянуто за уши, но все же дескриптор более менее _число_, и более менее _номер_.

Comment: Да, насчёт № это прям хорошо